# Toggle between two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Currently I have a button which changes its text from Pause to Resume when clicking on it. I use jQuery and toggle for this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pause").click(function() {
      $("td").toggle();
      $(this).html($(this).html() == "Pause" ? "Resume" : "Pause");
    });
});
```

This all works. I also have 2 functions:

```
function pauseTimer() 
function startTimer()
```

How do I "integrate" these two functions into my toggle code? So when I hit Pause it will toggle the text to Resume AND also use the function `pauseTimer()` and if I hit the button again, the text will change back to Pause and also use `StartTimer()`?

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the docs? http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Just turn the ternary statement in to a normal `if` condition containing the two statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I completely misinterpreted your question this should do it:

```
$("#pause").click(function() {
  $("td").toggle();
  if($(this).html() == "Pause")
  {
      $(this).html("Resume");
      pauseTimer();
  }else{
      $(this).html("Pause");
      startTimer();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks all, I have chosen this one, suited me best

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).html() == "Pause" ? pauseTimer() : startTimer();
```

Will work. You have to change the html content of the element to Start or Pause in the functions so that the function will run alternatively according to the html of the element.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
var doStuff = function(callback, text){
    callback();
    return text;
}
$(this).html($(this).html() == "Pause" ? doStuff(startTimer, "Resume") : doStuff(StartTimer, "Pause"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var globalTimerPaused = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pause").click(function() {
      $("td").toggle();
      $(this).html($(this).html() == "Pause" ? "Resume" : "Pause");
      if(!globalTimerPaused){ pauseTimer() } else { startTimer() };
      globalTimerPaused = !globalTimerPaused;
    });
});
```

Comment: use mine in scenarios where you have need to access the state of the timer in blocks of code outside the if statement

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('selector').click(function () { // on click event
  var song = $('theaudiotag');
  if(song.paused) { // if song is paused
     $(this).play(); // play it
     $(this).html('Pause'); // change text
  } else { // otherwise
     $(this).pause(); // pause it
     $(this).html('Play'); // change text
  }
}
```

This uses `jQuery` API to check for the current status of the audio tag, and then toggle its state to `play` or `pause` and at the same time. It will work cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `window` method here like:

```
$("#pause").click(function () {
    $("td").toggle();
    $(this).html($(this).html() == "Pause" ? "Resume" : "Pause");
    window[$(this).html() === "Resume" ? "pauseTimer" : "startTimer"]();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery is visible method:

```
if ($('td').is(":visible"))
{
pauseTimer();
}
else
{
startTimer()
}
```

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to do the following.

```
//jQuery 1.8 toggle replacement
$.fn.toggleClick = function(){
    var methods = arguments,
        count = methods.length;
    return this.each(function(i, item){
        var index = 0;
        $(item).click(function(){
            return methods[index++ % count].apply(this,arguments);
        });
    });
};

function startTime() {
    $("td").toggle();
    $(this).val("Start");
}

function pauseTime() {
    $("td").toggle();
    $(this).val("Pause");
}

$("#clickme").toggleClick(startTime,pauseTime);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q34R/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#pause").click(function(pauseTimer(),StartTimer()) {
  $("td").toggle();
  $(this).html($(this).html() == "Pause" ? "Resume" : "Pause");
});
});
```